# OpcUaServer - Unable to create nodes imported from Euromap77 Nodeset XML file

Tags: c#, .net, opc-ua, node-set

I'm trying to import an standard Euromap77 Nodeset from an XML file on a Asp.Net application (https://www.euromap.org/euromap77), using OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua Nuget Packages (version 1.4.368.53)

I found a guide that explains how to import a nodeset file and run a server, but it does not seem to work for me (https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues/546#issuecomment-425331836 this is the exact code i'm using to run the server)

The import seems to work fine, but whenhen I navigate it using UaExpert, the nodes are not there, except for the server default

[image]

Am I missing some configurations?
Feel free to ask for more informations,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the  sourcecode of your server (should inherit from StandardServer) and node manager (should inherit from CustomNodeManager2)